# GET/POST vs USE in ExpressJS for filtering URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

router.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
console.log('first middleware function'+req.originalUrl)

})

**VS**

router.use('/',(req,res,next)=>{
console.log('first middleware function'+req.originalUrl)

})

Can anyone please help me when i use **USE** in second code if i put any url after / like '/jhds' so that middleware function runs but when i use **GET** in first code and put any url after / again like '/jhsd' it doesnt run, so how filtering works in use and get/post?

Comment: Are you using the GET method from frontend when using first option ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want the middleware to run **only for GET** requests to the / route, use router.get('/').
2. If you want the middleware to run for any HTTP method(GET, POST, PUT, etc.) on the / route and **its sub-routes**(/, /jhds, /jhsd, etc.), use router.use('/').

So, in summary, **use** is more generic and matches any method and path that starts with the specified path. **get** is specific to GET requests and matches only the exact path specified.